# How to create a script to check the website is using WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a simple script that'll let me know if a website is based off WordPress.

The idea is to check whether I'm getting a 404 from a URL when trying to access its wp-admin like so:

`https://www.audi.co.il/wp-admin` (which returns "true" because it exists)

When I try to input a URL that does not exist, like "https://www.audi.co.il/wp-blablabla", PHP still returns "true", even though Chrome, when pasting this link to its address bar returns 404 on the network tab.

Why is it so and how can it be fixed?

This is the code (based on another user's answer):

```
<?php 

$file = 'https://www.audi.co.il/wp-blabla';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if(!$file_headers || strpos($file_headers[0], '404 Not Found')) {
    $exists = "false";
}
else {
    $exists = "true";
}
echo $exists;
```

Comment: Who says WP has to go in the root of the site?  I never install it in the webroot directory.  I also use HTACCESS to ban all the IP but mine for the admin folder... :).  Probably be better off with CURL.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It is quite common where I come from, and that's what I'm trying to achieve with that question - finding out by checking the url.

Comment: It looks like that site is returning a page with JavaScript that does a redirect. The 404 error is happening during the redirect, not when accessing the initial URL.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so it is not possible to achieve?

Comment: I would think that WordPress would redirect this  `https://www.audi.co.il/wp-blabla` to `index.php` because of  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, at least typically.

Comment: You could download the `wp-admin` page and then scrape it to see if it looks like a typical WP admin page.

Comment: I am not sure how common this is  `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.9.6" />`  But I see it on a lot of WP sites too.  That reminds me I should update this copy of Wordpress, not to worry it's on localhost, working on making a LMS plugin :-), well if I wasn't slacking off on here.  I leave in like 3 minutes ... ha ha ha.

Comment: So no way to achieve what I'm looking for with php?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find the wp-admin page and if it is not there then there's a good change it's not WordPress.

```
function isWordPress($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    if ( $httpStatus == 200 ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if ( isWordPress("http://www.example.com/wp-admin") ) {
    // This is WordPress
} else {
    // Not WordPress
}
```

This may not be one hundred percent accurate as some WordPress installations protect the wp-admin URL.

Comment: Thanks so much but it didn't work for me yet. I specified this argument: https://www.audi.co.il/wp-admin which should return true but it keeps giving me false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party but another way you can easily determine a WordPress site is by crawling the /wp-json. If you're using Guzzle by PHP, you can do this:

```
 function isWorpress($url) {
     try {
         $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
         $response = $http->get(rtrim($url, "/")."/wp-json");
         $contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

         if($contents) {
             return true;
         }
     } catch (\Exception $exception) {
         //...
     }

     return false;
 }
```